# UWP Template10 Frame.Navigate with parameter causes Error

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, template10

Was developing UWP project by using Intense Templates(SplitView sample) then I switched to Template10(Hamburger). And seems there is error when I try to pass parameter

`param is string with value something like this - (d5d05a3b-546a-4ca6-a345-74e333fa00fb)
Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditPage),param);`

Error is something like this:
[ErrorPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Rxj.png)
And then if my Edit page cant get right **param**,  It will send user back (`Frame.GoBack()`), now I'm getting error like

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in App6.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard to debug a verbal description of your code :)  Can you please *edit your question* and add in the relevant code snippets so that we can see what you've got and then we can help you debug that code. (don't put the code in the comments here because the formatting is awful) :)

Answer (score 1):

the root cause of your problem, if I were to guess (and based on the exception string) is that you are passing to your page a complex type that cannot be serialized. The reason Template 10 wants to serialize your parameter is so it can correctly restore your navigation state after your app is suspended. I realize this is inconvenient if you MUST pass a non serializable object, and so you will discover BootStrapper.SessionState (a Dictionary) allows you do hold objects of any kind, requiring you to only pass the key to the page that can use SessionState + that key to retrieve the object.

This is a great pattern, by the way, and certainly not one unique to Template 10. The only thing I would add to this would be you assume the object is missing from the dictionary and include the defensive code to handle that situation too. The reason is, this situation could occur if your app has been suspended.

I hope this makes sense. And, don't feel bad. You are certainly not the first to ask this question.

```
var key = nameof(MyObject);
SessionState.Add(key, MyObject);
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage), key);
```