# Item added to ObservableCollection lost on Navigate

Tags: uwp, observablecollection, template10

Starting from a Template10 Hamburger template I have a typical master/detail scenario for managing recipes. The data structure is RecipeBox contains RecipeGroups which contain Recipes. Here's a bit of the UI to give you a better idea:

[image: RecipeMaster UI]

I have an `AppBarButton` linked to a method to add a new Recipe to the collection. It's a pretty simple method:

```
private async Task createNewRecipe()
{
    NewNamedItemDialog dialog = new NewNamedItemDialog("Enter New Recipe Name");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();

    Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe(dialog.TextEntry);            
    currentGroup.Recipes.Add(newRecipe);
    SelectedRecipe = newRecipe;

   // goToRecipeView();
}
```

Notice I've got the last line commented. When it's in play, `NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), newRecipe)` will correctly display the detail view with the new Recipe object, but the collection is not updated. When I go back from the DetailView the Recipe has not been added to the Group. Simply disabling the immediate navigation allows the `ObservableCollection<RecipeGroup>` to be updated correctly.

How can I trigger the updating of the collection and still perform the immediate navigation to edit my new item?

Why does `NavigationService.Navigate` interrupt the updating of my local objects?

!!!  Updated section below !!!

Here is a simple example demonstrating my lack of knowledge in this arena. This project has a simple Key-Value class, and the start page displays a simple list of these that's created when the app is launched:

[Sample Project](http://craigcad.us/ss/NavigationDemo.zip)

When the app is launched it shows two items in a GridView, you can select one to edit, or you can add a new one (which takes you directly to the DetailPage to edit).

[image: Start Grid View]

The DetailPage simply displays a TextBox to edit the Value:

[image: Detail Page View]

Since I handle the click of the AppBarButton I can pass the selected DataItem to the DetailPage as a parameter. This raises these questions which I'm still working to resolve.

1. I can pass information as parameters to `NavigationService.Navigate()`, so when navigating through methods I declare I can pass data -- but how do I do that when the user clicks the back button? I tried similar approaches by adding in parameters in `OnNavigatingFrom()` without much luck.
2. Jerry had stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524171/template-10-navigation-service-serialization) that the serialization service used for the passing of parameters has a size limit of about 8 Kb, and of course some objects don't serialize well. He recommended a "session cache" for dealing with such situations which doesn't ring a bell for me. What is the recommended best practice for passing large or complex objects between pages in a UWP app ?

Comment: Application/Page state, SQLite, JSON file all viable solutions.... Hell SettingServices with a  `ObservableCollection<RecipeGroup>` would work.  Think of it as a function of comfort level with complexity... Obviously SQLite would probably be overkill

Comment: I have a service to save data to Json files, my issue is with run-time objects being updated, Template10 NavigationService seems to interrupt that.

Comment: With the code you've posted, it's hard to say why you have this issue. Could you please share more details like where you define the  `ObservableCollection` and how you use it with the `createNewRecipe` method? A [mcve] would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Mr. Nixon cleared this up in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398860/uwp-template10-frame-navigate-with-parameter-causes-error/37417911), sorry I hadn't found it sooner.

It doesn't entirely answer my original question but it gives me enough information to work around that issue.